# Не удается реализовать метод Delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Сделал список пользователей в json файле и запустил на локальном сервере(json-server). Нужно удалить нужный элемент массива по нажатию кнопки.

Это инстанс у аксиос.

```
export const deleteUsers = (id, user) => {
return instance.delete(`people/${id}`)
.then(response => {
    return response
})
```

}

Фрагмент запроса на сервер на хуках:

```
const removeUsers = (id) => ({type: DELETE_USERS, id})

const remove = async (id) => {
    const response = await deleteUsers()
    if(response.data.resultCode === 0) {
        dispatch(removeUsers(id))
    }
}
```

Сама форма:

```
const {remove} = useContext(UsersContext)
const onDelete = () => {
  remove(id)
}
return (
    <div className="card mb-4">
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{name}</h5>
        <button onClick={onDelete} className="btn btn-outline-dark my-1 my-sm-0 mr-1">Delete</button>
        <button className="btn btn-outline-dark my-1 my-sm-0">Change</button>
      </div>
    </div>
)
```

Проблема в том, что когда я пробую удалить один из элементов массива вместо айди падает undefined.
Хотя при выводе в консоль показывается нужное значение. 
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не передали в `deleteUsers` никаких аргументов. Хотя по сигнатуре она требует `id` и `user`.

Comment: В таком случае user и id нужно передать в сам инстанс с delete как объект? Если правильно понимаю.

Comment: Вы же написали код сверху. Я думаю, для вас не проблема вызвать функцию с аргументами